# Iterative function eventually reaching identity

Tags: number-theory, functions, invariance

For integers $a,b$ we define $f((a,b))=(2a,b-a)$ if $a<b$ and $f((a,b))=(a-b,2b)$ if $a\geq b$.
Given a natural number $n>1$ show that there exist natural numbers $m,k$ with $m<n$ such that $f^{k}((n,m))=(m,n)$,where 
$f^{k}(x)=f(f(f(...f(x))))$,$f$ being composed with itself $k$ times.
Also, is there an explicit form of $k$ using $m,n$? If yes, then find it or prove otherwise.

This is a problem from the Indian Team Selection Test for IMO. I was trying this one, but I have no idea about it. I can only see that the sum of the variables remain constant, i.e $a+b=2a+(b-a)=2b+(a-b)$. But how to use this fact? And I also couldn't guess what could be the length. The expressions seem to point towards $\gcd$ but I have no proof. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to find such $(m,k)$ for small $n$ (and maybe some excluded values like $-1$, $0$ and $1$). Maybe you can spot a pattern. Since the sum is constant, $f_s(a)$ is fixed given the sum  $s$ of the two elements, so only a sequence in one term remains.

Comment: No, I haven't. It will be tedious since I don't know any programming or something of the sort. Now you say so, I think I should try some values.

Comment: Note that the sequence will be something like $a_1\to a_2\to a_3\to\dots$, where $a_{n+1}=2a_n$ if $a_n<\frac 12 s$ and $s-a_n$ else.

Comment: Wow, really?? I am still as clueless as I was. Please post the solution dear @Ragnar. Also please post the complete solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I am waiting. :)

Comment: Hmm, maybe something is wrong with it, because in my solution there exists a good $k$ for every $n$ and $m$... Found the problem, not so trivial after all...

Comment: Oh, I see. But maybe your solution is correct? Did you check carefully? @Ragnar

Comment: no, I thought that the sequence is a bijection, but $(1,9)\to (2,8)$ and $(6,4)\to(2,8)$, so it is not.